# Mobile Safari, How to bring the navigation bar back?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, mobile-safari, iscroll

I'm using iScroll 4 and preventing the default window scroll from happening. By doing this, the navigation bar is visible every time you're scrolling, this because it relies on the window scroll to show or hide this accordingly, you can hide it though by doing:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 1);
```

I thought by doing the reverse I could get the navigaton url bar back, but that won't happen. Let's suppose the navigation bar is height = 70

```
window.scrollTo(0, 70);
```

I'm trying to figure out the reason of this happening. Why can't I just revert what I did initially ? I'd like to rely on the event onScrollMove of iscroll and show or hide the navigation bar accordingly (or close to the native way):

```
iscrollInstance.onScrollMove: function(){
   // var y = iscrollInstance.y;
   // window.scrollTo(0, y); if y let's say is >= 0 and <= 70
}
```

This may be nice to help understand what's going on:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <div class="iscroll"></div>
</div>
```

- when the document is ready, there's a hack that basically makes the iscroll height a big bigger and the container, so that when doing the window.scrollTo(0, 1) the navigation bar is not visible. Just remember that the default default scroll is being prevented and the iscroll only works in it's own container.
- I'd like to mention that the full page is not being scrolled just the ".iscroll" element, let's say if container is 100%, the nav would be 20% and the iscroll let's say 80%

Comment: Let's back up a bit: why are you iScrolling the entire page at all?

Comment: @Blazemonger hi, thanks for looking! Only the container ".iscroll" is being scrolled. Let's say .container { height: 100%; }; .nav { 20%; }; .iscroll { height: 80%; };